# Stretch list elements to full container width

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I want to make unordered list(ul) elements(li) stretched to its container width. List is generated automatically. It can be 3, 4 or 10 elements. What I need you can see in attached image:

[image]

HTML and CSS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stretch list elements to full container width</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container{
            width:100%;
        }
        ul{
            height:20px;
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            list-style:none;
            border:1px solid #000;
        }

        ul li{
            float:left;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    What I have:<br>

    <div id="container">
      <ul>
        <li style="background-color:red">element 1</li>
        <li style="background-color:green">element 2</li>
        <li style="background-color:blue">element 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <br><br>   
    What I need:
    <br>

     <div id="container">
      <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color:red">element 1</td>
            <td style="background-color:green">element 2</td>
            <td style="background-color:blue">element 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It is easy to implement this task with table. But how to do it with unordered(ul) list?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this http://jsfiddle.net/38F9V/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var num = $('li').length;
   var width_li = 100/num;
   $('li').css('width',width_li+'%');
});
```

calculate number of li elements, and divide total width with that length, then set the width of each li element using jquery

Comment: This is really nice!! Can it be done with images in a certain div to? Make all the images share "the" 100% of the container div.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:`ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
}`

Comment: List is generated automatically. It can be 3, 4 or 10 elements.

Comment: @Bounce You didn't say in the question.